# Accessibility of a photonsphere in Schwarzschild space-time

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, complex-systems

The schwarzschild geometry allows a photonsphere in the radius 3M. In the sense of dinamical systems, the photonsphere is a saddle fixed point, which means that it's unstable under small perturbations in the phasespace. Integrating the equations of motion for null geodesics we can find the following solution,

$$
x(\gamma) = -\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\tanh^{2}\left(\frac{\gamma + \gamma_{0}}{2}\right) \,\, ,
$$

where $x(\gamma):=M/r(\gamma)$, and it is a homoclinic orbit what can be seen taking the limit $\lim_{\gamma \to \pm \infty} x(\gamma) = 1/3$. It means that and null geodesic begining in $r=\infty$ tends to $r=3M$, towards and backwards in the the parameter $\gamma$. My question is in the physical space, is it possible to reach and stay caught in the photonsphere? If it's possible, what does the limit of $\gamma \to \pm \infty$ mean on the physical space? What interpretation can I make to the limit $\gamma \to -\infty$?

Comment: Related question: [Stability of Photon Orbits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/380111/75633).

Comment: This question is also mine, but there are not the interpratations I'm asking here.

Comment: Sure, I noticed the author and the difference - that's why I didn't mark as a duplicate. But the relation exists, right?

Comment: It is probably not clear to a general reader what $\gamma$ is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as pointed out my answer to [stability of photon orbits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/380111/75633), this is a formal solution to equation of motion. More precisely it is a solution to the radial part of the equation of motion. The are not physical in the sense that some finite intervals in $\gamma$ will cover an infinite amount of coordinate time.

However individual ranges of $\gamma$ can correspond to physical geodesics. For example, if we choose $\gamma_0$ such that for $\gamma >0$ $x(\gamma)>0$, we find a geodesic that starts at infinity ($x=0$) and asymptotes to the lightring (photonsphere) as $\gamma\to\infty$ (and $t\to\infty$). If you will this is a lightray that gets "stuck" on the lightring. This of course is a highly fine tuned solution. Any perturbation, and either the lightray crosses the lightring and plunges into the black hole, or it just scatters away to infinity.

Similarly, we can choose $\gamma_0$ such that $x(\gamma)>0$ for $\gamma<0$. This will correspond to a solution with coordinate time running from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ while $\gamma$ runs from $-\infty$ to $0$. This is a null ray asymptotically escaping from the lightring. I.e. as solution that for very negative $\gamma$ deviates exponentially from the lightring.